# Custom Theme - Add page specific meta tags / title to pages

Tags: theming, 8, nodes, meta-tags

I am new to Drupal, but I am very familiar with WordPress.

In WordPress, I am able to hook into the head of a document with `wp_head` to add things like page specific meta tags.

When using a custom theme based on Stable, how would you add page specific things in the `<head>` of a document in Drupal 8?

Note: I am wondering how this would be done without a custom module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the tag to the page's render array via [`hook_page_attachments_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.4.x).

An example from the [related change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2160069):

```
function MYTHEME_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
    $viewport = array(
        '#type' => 'html_tag',
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'name' => 'viewport',
            'content' => 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no',
        ),
    );
    $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$viewport, 'viewport'];
}
```

Comment: Nice.  Where would I be able to find all of the # keys available to me?  I viewed the contents of `$page` and it looks like I have one key `#attached`  with `library`, `html_head_link`, `html_head` as sub keys.  Are there others that I could add?

Comment: Anywhere, really - the # properties are arbitrary, they describe meta info about the render array and can be literally any valid string that starts with a `#`. The method that renders whatever element type the property is on decides what to do with it. It's better to approach it as "what do I need to do?" rather than "what are all the things I could do?", as it's basically infinite by nature